# Date in column headers of attendance list

Tags: php, html, date

I want to make an attendance list in which the date entered in the input form is put in the header of the right 3rd column. In the headers of the following columns, this date is incremented by 7 days.

I have three questions:

1. Why is the date not filled in the headers?
2. How can I insert the html table in the if statement?
3. How can I make the width of date columns 1 character big?

I created an input form `forum.php` and an action-script `gen-table.php`.

Inputform `forum.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
td, th {
  border: 4px solid lightblue;
  text-align: left;
  padding: px;
}
</style>
<h2> ATTENDANCE LIST </h2>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="gen-table.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="startdate">Startdate:</label>
        <input type="date" name="startdate" id="startdate" />
        <input type="submit" value="Select and Activate" />
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Action script `gen-table.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
td, th {
  border: 4px solid lightblue;
  text-align: left;
  padding: px;
}
</style>
<h2> ATTENDANCE LIST </h2>
</head>

<?php
if (isset($_POST[startdate])) {
$day1 = date('d-m-Y',strtotime(startdate ."+0 Days"));
$day2 = date('d-m-Y',strtotime(startdate ."+7 Days"));
$day3 = date('d-m-Y',strtotime(startdate ."+14 Days"));
$day4 = date('d-m-Y',strtotime(startdate ."+21 Days"));
}
else
{
    echo "Select startdate";
}
?>

<table>

    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <td><?php print $day1 ?>&nbsp;</td><td><?php echo $day2 ?></td><td><?php echo $day3 ?>&nbsp;</td><td><?php echo $day4 ?>&nbsp;</td>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you se in the browsers View Source feature for this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 1.** Dates are not generating correctly. Inside `strtotime()` you should pass value from `$_POST` array.

Replace

```
date('d-m-Y',strtotime(startdate ."+0 Days"));
...
```

to

```
date('d-m-Y',strtotime($_POST['startdate'] . "+0 Days"));
...
```

**Answer 2.** You can dump html table with condition as follows-

```
<?php if(condition is true): ?>
     html <table> goes here
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Answer 3.** Question is confusing, but according to my assumption you can use font size to make text bigger or use padding to give your text big space.

Comment: Thanks. It works. One qeustion. I get this warning: Warning: Use of undefined constant startdate - assumed 'startdate' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP).

Comment: Use $_POST["startdate"] instead of $_POST[startdate].
One more thing is if the answer helps you you can accept the answer.